# Is it possible to access @task with mylyn?

Tags: eclipse, task, mylyn

It looks like we are migrating our from Jira to [@task](http://www.attask.com/) for our feature requests/bug tracking.  Does anyone know if @task can be accessed from [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen an @task connector in the [supported list](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions).

There's a means to [discover available connectors](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Discovery) through Mylyn.

You can see a list of requested connectors and [vote](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=anywordssubstr&short_desc=%5Bconnector%5D&product=Mylyn&long_desc_type=allwordssubstr&long_desc=&bug_file_loc_type=allwordssubstr&bug_file_loc=&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr&status_whiteboard=&keywords_type=allwords&keywords=&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&emailtype1=substring&email1=&emailtype2=substring&email2=&bugidtype=include&bug_id=&votes=&chfieldfrom=&chfieldto=Now&chfieldvalue=&cmdtype=doit&order=Reuse+same+sort+as+last+time&field0-0-0=noop&type0-0-0=noop&value0-0-0=) that a connector be created.

Answer (score 0):

[Google searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=attask+mylyn+connector) and [the official connector listing](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/Extensions#Task_Repository_Connectors) seem to indicate that there is no such connector.